# ValueError: view limit minimum -0.5 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value when plotting to a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting this error only sometimes when I try to plot a bar chart with the value_counts() of the multinomialnb_label values in the dataframe.
Other times it is fine. I can't figure out how to fix the error.

It is part of a flask application and everything works fine until it hits the line:

```
my_plot = multinomialnb_count.plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```

Here is the multinomialnb_count details:

```
[1395 rows x 15 columns]
bug report        721
question          492
praise            112
noise              49
other feedback     21
Name: multinomialnb_label, dtype: int64
```

Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymysql.cursors
import sqlalchemy
import datetime
import sys
import re
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import preprocessor as p
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import collections
import contractions
from matplotlib import rcParams

def make_charts(username):

    rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

    username = username
    new_db_name = username + "_predicted_tweets"

    # Get tweets from MYSQL database
    dbServerName = "localhost"
    dbUser = "root"
    dbPassword = "woodycool123"
    dbName = "azure_support_tweets"

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:woodycool123@localhost:3306/azure_support_tweets')
    df = pd.read_sql_table(new_db_name, engine)
    data = pd.DataFrame(df)

    multinomialnb_count = data['multinomialnb_label'].value_counts()
    my_plot = multinomialnb_count.plot(kind='bar', legend=None)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -0.5 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Answer (score 7):

Solved it! It was as simple as just closing the plt at the end of the function with `plt.close().`

It was because the plt was configured for a time series further down and then when the script was rerun it was using that. I assumed it would clear all the values but you have to close that plt to then use a new one! Thanks

Comment: Similarly, I was reusing an old axes object due to a copy & paste error. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this took me forever to figure out.  In Databricks, I just had to put the plot in a different cell.