# ValueError: view limit minimum -35738.3640567 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

I’m trying to plot a dataframe using `matplotlib.pyplot`, but I get the following error when plotting:

```py
ValueError: view limit minimum -35738.3640567 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units.
```

According to the error, it seems like there's a non-datetime value in the `'datetime'` column, but there isn't.

I've tried using `pd.to_datetime()` to change the format of the timestamp with `pd.to_datetime(df_google['datetime'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')`, but nothing changes.

This is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_google.plot()
plt.show()
```

`df_google` is a dataframe with columns `['datetime', 'price']` and some of the values are the following:

```
     datetime        price
0  2018-05-15  1079.229980
1  2018-05-16  1081.770020
2  2018-05-17  1078.589966
3  2018-05-18  1066.359985
4  2018-05-21  1079.579956
5  2018-05-22  1069.729980
6  2018-05-23  1079.689941
7  2018-05-24  1079.239990
8  2018-05-25  1075.660034
9  2018-05-29  1060.319946
```

Can someone try to help me understand this type of error? Why does it say there's a non-datetime value when every value is a `datetime Dtype` value? How can I plot this dataframe?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Set the `'datetime'` column to a `datetime64[ns] Dtype` to resolve the error:

  - Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `'datetime'` column, and remember to assign the column back to itself, because this is not an inplace update.
  - `pandas` is good at figuring out the format of datetimes, but it may be necessary to use the `format=` option to *specify the current format* of the `'datetime'` column. See [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26763344/7758804).
- Column names can be accessed with a `.`, if they do not contain special characters, and do not clash with built-in attributes/methods (e.g., `index`, `count`).

  - `df_google.datetime` instead of `df_google['datetime']`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# given the following data
data = {'datetime': ['2018-05-15', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-18', '2018-05-21', '2018-05-22', '2018-05-23', '2018-05-24', '2018-05-25', '2018-05-29'],
        'price': [1079.22998, 1081.77002, 1078.589966, 1066.359985, 1079.579956, 1069.72998, 1079.689941, 1079.23999, 1075.660034, 1060.319946]}

df_google = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the datetime column to a datetime type and assign it back to the column
df_google.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df_google.datetime)

# display(df_google.head())
     datetime        price
0  2018-05-15  1079.229980
1  2018-05-16  1081.770020
2  2018-05-17  1078.589966
3  2018-05-18  1066.359985
4  2018-05-21  1079.579956
5  2018-05-22  1069.729980
6  2018-05-23  1079.689941
7  2018-05-24  1079.239990
8  2018-05-25  1075.660034
9  2018-05-29  1060.319946
```

#### Verify the `'datetime'` column is a `datetime64[ns]` Dtype:

```py
print(df_google.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   datetime  10 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   price     10 non-null     float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

#### Plot:

- Specify the column to be the axis with `x=...` to plot.

```py
df_google.plot(x='datetime')
plt.show()
```

- The column to be the x-axis can also be set as the index with `df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)`, and then `df.plot()` to plot, but setting the index is not necessary, and is irrelevant to the error.
- There's a substantial ecosystem of alternative plotting tools, but `df.plot()` is fine for getting a look at the data.

  - [PyViz](https://pyviz.org/overviews/index.html)

[image]

#### Note:

- This solution was for this OP, however, there is a similar question, [ValueError: view limit minimum -0.5 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value when plotting to a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53692186/7758804), with a different solution.
- Make sure `pandas` and `matplotlib` are update.

  - If you are using Anaconda, update with `conda upate --all`. Do not use `pip` to update packages installed with Anaconda.
- If you are using a notebook, try restarting the kernel and clearing outputs.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem just now. The output was

```
view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

I set `int` limit for my x-values, although I had `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`
values in my 'Release_Date' column

```
with sns.axes_style('darkgrid'):
  ax = sns.scatterplot(data=data_clean,
                  # Release_Date column has pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp in it
                  x='Release_Date',
                  y='USD_Worldwide_Gross',
                  )


  ax.set(ylim=(0, 3000000000),
        # xlim caused problem, because of int values
        xlim=(0, 450000000))

  plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question in the OP. This is not helpful in relation to the existing question and data.