# Matplotlib error: date = ValueError: view limit minimum -36881.85 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I am trying to plot timeseries with subplots, and my index is a datetime object with daily values in one column.

My DataFrame is:

```
            close
date    
2009-12-16  147237.339062
2009-12-17  143635.850193
2009-12-18  143328.664378
2009-12-21  141941.031902
2009-12-22  144366.740581
...     ...
2020-07-27  104150.000000
2020-07-28  103900.000000
2020-07-29  105400.000000
2020-07-30  105850.000000
2020-07-31  103100.000000

2627 rows × 1 columns
```

And my code is:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(9,7), 'figure.dpi':120})

# Original Series
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True)
axes[0, 0].plot(df.close); axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
plot_acf(df.close, ax=axes[0, 1])

# 1st Differencing
axes[1, 0].plot(df.close.diff()); axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.close.diff().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])

# 2nd Differencing
axes[2, 0].plot(df.close.diff().diff()); axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.close.diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])

plt.show()
```

index is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2009-12-16', '2009-12-17', '2009-12-18', '2009-12-21',
               '2009-12-22', '2009-12-23', '2009-12-28', '2009-12-29',
               '2009-12-30', '2010-01-04',
               ...
               '2020-07-20', '2020-07-21', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-23',
               '2020-07-24', '2020-07-27', '2020-07-28', '2020-07-29',
               '2020-07-30', '2020-07-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=2627, freq=None)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -36881.85 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Full error stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    332                 pass
    333             else:
--> 334                 return printer(obj)
    335             # Finally look for special method names
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

14 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    239 
    240     if 'png' in formats:
--> 241         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    242     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    243         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    123 
    124     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 125     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    126     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    127     if fmt == 'svg':

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
   2098                            else suppress())
   2099                     with ctx:
-> 2100                         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2101                     bbox_artists = kwargs.pop("bbox_extra_artists", None)
   2102                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1734             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1735             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1736                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1737 
   1738             renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    135     if not_composite or not has_images:
    136         for a in artists:
--> 137             a.draw(renderer)
    138     else:
    139         # Composite any adjacent images together

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     36                 renderer.start_filter()
     37 
---> 38             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39         finally:
     40             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2588                 artists.remove(spine)
   2589 
-> 2590         self._update_title_position(renderer)
   2591 
   2592         if not self.axison or inframe:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _update_title_position(self, renderer)
   2531                 if (ax.xaxis.get_ticks_position() in ['top', 'unknown']
   2532                         or ax.xaxis.get_label_position() == 'top'):
-> 2533                     bb = ax.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
   2534                 else:
   2535                     bb = ax.get_window_extent(renderer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_tightbbox(self, renderer)
   1184             return
   1185 
-> 1186         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
   1187 
   1188         self._update_label_position(renderer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _update_ticks(self)
   1101         the axes.  Return the list of ticks that will be drawn.
   1102         """
-> 1103         major_locs = self.get_majorticklocs()
   1104         major_labels = self.major.formatter.format_ticks(major_locs)
   1105         major_ticks = self.get_major_ticks(len(major_locs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_majorticklocs(self)
   1346     def get_majorticklocs(self):
   1347         """Get the array of major tick locations in data coordinates."""
-> 1348         return self.major.locator()
   1349 
   1350     def get_minorticklocs(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self)
   1336     def __call__(self):
   1337         'Return the locations of the ticks'
-> 1338         self.refresh()
   1339         return self._locator()
   1340 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in refresh(self)
   1362     def refresh(self):
   1363         # docstring inherited
-> 1364         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1365         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1366 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
   1096                              'often happens if you pass a non-datetime '
   1097                              'value to an axis that has datetime units'
-> 1098                              .format(vmin))
   1099         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
   1100 

ValueError: view limit minimum -36881.85 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

### Data [file.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15eLGeT5cbajN2T_M-8TJzZOVj_JJpvY8/view?usp=sharing)

- Subset of data incase link dies

```py
date,close
2009-12-16,147237.34
2009-12-17,143635.85
2009-12-18,143328.66
2009-12-21,141941.03
2009-12-22,144366.74
2009-12-23,144801.04
2009-12-28,145722.6
2009-12-29,146432.3
2009-12-30,146495.86
2010-01-04,150171.49
2010-01-05,150521.05
2010-01-06,151432.01
2010-01-07,150563.42
2010-01-08,150616.38
2010-01-11,150542.23
2010-01-12,149821.94
2010-01-13,150288.01
2010-01-14,149228.75
2010-01-15,147237.34
2010-01-18,147957.64
2010-01-19,149027.49
2010-01-20,145034.08
2010-01-21,140818.21
2010-01-22,140140.29
2010-01-26,138890.36
2010-01-27,137598.06
2010-01-28,139398.8
2010-01-29,138254.8
2010-02-01,141157.18
2010-02-02,142534.22
2010-02-03,142375.33
2010-02-04,135267.68
2010-02-05,133043.24
2010-02-08,133583.46
2010-02-09,136665.91
2010-02-10,137809.91
2010-02-11,139970.81
2010-02-12,139653.03
2010-02-17,142358.09
2010-02-18,143542.83
2010-02-19,143207.33
2010-02-22,142274.21
2010-02-23,140282.16
2010-02-24,139202.26
2010-02-25,139485.34
2010-02-26,140491.85
2010-03-01,142483.9
2010-03-02,143333.14
2010-03-03,143008.12
2010-03-04,143427.5
2010-03-05,145461.49
2010-03-08,144507.4
2010-03-09,147034.16
2010-03-10,148145.51
2010-03-11,147830.98
2010-03-12,146226.85
2010-03-15,145629.24
2010-03-16,147747.1
2010-03-17,147243.85
2010-03-18,147097.06
2010-03-19,145000.17
2010-03-22,145713.12
2010-03-23,146258.31
2010-03-24,145063.08
2010-03-25,143846.88
2010-03-26,144580.79
2010-03-29,147369.66
2010-03-30,147128.52
2010-03-31,148082.6
2010-04-01,149298.8
2010-04-05,149843.99
2010-04-06,149319.77
2010-04-07,148827.0
2010-04-08,150850.5
2010-04-09,149875.45
2010-04-12,148040.67
2010-04-13,148533.44
2010-04-14,149340.86
2010-04-15,147705.44
2010-04-16,145386.87
2010-04-19,144517.4
2010-04-20,145076.34
2010-04-22,145117.75
2010-04-23,145221.26
2010-04-26,143772.15
2010-04-27,138658.87
2010-04-28,139114.3
2010-04-29,142012.52
2010-04-30,141184.46
2010-05-03,140490.96
2010-05-04,135388.03
2010-05-05,135853.81
2010-05-06,132282.8
2010-05-07,130626.67
2010-05-10,136733.63
2010-05-11,134042.43
2010-05-12,135905.57
2010-05-13,134901.54
2010-05-14,131827.36
2010-05-17,130875.09
2010-05-18,126610.58
2010-05-19,124012.53
2010-05-20,120814.15
2010-05-21,125171.82
2010-05-24,124302.36
2010-05-25,123070.61
2010-05-26,123650.26
2010-05-27,128960.2
2010-05-28,128349.51
2010-05-31,130316.15
2010-06-01,128349.51
2010-06-02,131247.72
2010-06-04,127728.46
2010-06-07,126796.89
2010-06-08,128194.24
2010-06-09,127417.94
2010-06-10,130626.67
2010-06-11,131848.06
2010-06-14,131361.58
2010-06-15,133524.89
2010-06-16,134156.89
2010-06-17,133606.31
2010-06-18,132892.6
2010-06-21,134360.8
2010-06-22,133952.97
2010-06-23,134789.03
2010-06-24,132240.07
2010-06-25,134258.85
2010-06-28,132668.29
2010-06-29,127764.09
2010-06-30,125266.11
2010-07-01,126224.52
2010-07-02,126336.68
2010-07-05,125419.05
2010-07-06,127855.86
2010-07-07,130394.62
2010-07-08,130710.69
2010-07-12,129619.74
2010-07-13,130710.69
2010-07-14,130364.03
2010-07-15,130608.73
2010-07-16,128059.77
2010-07-19,129915.42
2010-07-20,132331.83
2010-07-21,132178.89
2010-07-22,135176.47
2010-07-23,136318.41
2010-07-26,136257.23
2010-07-27,136991.33
2010-07-28,136695.65
2010-07-29,137236.03
2010-07-30,138276.01
2010-08-02,140315.18
2010-08-03,139275.2
2010-08-04,139835.97
2010-08-05,140294.78
2010-08-06,139417.94
2010-08-09,138367.77
2010-08-10,137531.71
2010-08-11,134116.1
2010-08-12,134544.33
2010-08-13,134809.42
2010-08-16,136359.19
2010-08-17,137888.57
2010-08-18,137427.77
2010-08-19,135804.37
2010-08-20,135664.08
2010-08-23,133800.17
2010-08-24,132367.17
2010-08-25,131254.84
2010-08-26,128889.89
2010-08-27,132768.01
2010-08-30,130072.37
2010-08-31,131745.87
2010-09-01,135924.62
2010-09-02,134962.61
2010-09-03,134301.22
2010-09-06,134692.04
2010-09-08,134241.1
2010-09-09,134331.29
2010-09-10,135163.03
2010-09-13,137407.73
2010-09-14,136726.3
2010-09-15,137447.81
2010-09-16,136656.15
2010-09-17,135203.11
2010-09-20,137708.36
2010-09-21,136606.05
2010-09-22,138269.53
2010-09-23,138660.35
2010-09-24,137968.9
2010-09-27,138600.22
2010-09-28,139702.53
2010-09-29,139672.47
2010-09-30,139552.22
2010-10-01,141486.27
2010-10-04,141305.89
2010-10-05,143229.92
2010-10-06,141596.5
2010-10-07,140353.9
2010-10-08,141957.25
2010-10-11,142077.51
2010-10-13,143889.57
2010-10-14,143672.89
2010-10-15,144086.54
2010-10-18,143121.37
2010-10-19,139240.98
2010-10-20,140816.77
2010-10-21,139950.08
2010-10-22,138650.05
2010-10-25,139063.7
2010-10-26,141259.96
2010-10-27,140541.01
2010-10-28,140245.54
2010-10-29,140934.95
2010-11-01,142313.77
2010-11-03,143613.8
2010-11-04,145307.78
2010-11-05,144677.46
2010-11-08,144795.65
2010-11-09,142215.29
2010-11-10,142313.77
2010-11-11,141614.51
2010-11-12,139792.5
2010-11-16,137093.96
2010-11-17,138177.32
2010-11-18,140265.24
2010-11-19,140442.52
2010-11-22,137881.86
2010-11-23,134356.02
2010-11-24,138098.53
2010-11-25,137389.42
2010-11-26,135006.03
2010-11-29,134552.99
2010-11-30,134237.84
2010-12-01,137113.66
2010-12-02,137241.69
2010-12-03,137822.76
2010-12-06,137034.87
2010-12-07,136010.6
2010-12-08,134139.35
2010-12-09,133755.25
2010-12-10,134572.69
2010-12-13,136148.48
2010-12-14,135124.22
2010-12-15,133217.31
2010-12-16,132065.47
2010-12-17,133585.13
2010-12-20,132336.49
2010-12-21,134156.21
2010-12-22,134165.89
2010-12-23,134253.01
2010-12-27,132994.69
2010-12-28,133691.6
2010-12-29,135395.17
2010-12-30,135317.74
2011-01-03,136740.61
2011-01-04,137834.38
2011-01-05,138812.0
2011-01-06,137892.45
2011-01-07,136517.98
2011-01-10,136905.16
2011-01-11,137766.62
2011-01-12,139876.73
2011-01-13,137853.74
2011-01-14,138444.18
2011-01-17,137427.84
2011-01-18,138424.82
2011-01-19,136256.64
2011-01-20,135279.02
2011-01-21,134446.6
2011-01-24,135220.95
2011-01-26,133604.49
2011-01-27,132200.98
2011-01-28,129432.68
2011-01-31,128880.95
2011-02-01,131862.2
2011-02-02,129297.16
2011-02-03,129384.28
2011-02-04,126161.05
2011-02-07,126606.3
2011-02-08,127535.52
2011-02-09,124447.79
2011-02-10,125173.75
2011-02-11,127187.06
2011-02-14,128735.76
2011-02-15,128503.46
2011-02-16,131161.09
2011-02-17,131189.77
2011-02-18,131868.51
2011-02-21,130367.62
2011-02-22,128761.56
2011-02-23,129440.31
2011-02-24,129191.76
2011-02-25,129612.39
2011-02-28,130396.3
2011-03-01,127652.62
2011-03-02,129860.95
2011-03-03,131505.24
2011-03-04,131562.6
2011-03-09,129660.19
2011-03-10,127337.15
2011-03-11,128579.93
2011-03-14,129784.47
2011-03-15,129249.12
2011-03-16,127126.83
2011-03-17,127079.03
2011-03-18,129249.12
2011-03-21,128293.13
2011-03-22,129813.15
2011-03-23,130530.14
2011-03-24,130166.86
2011-03-25,130434.54
2011-03-28,129038.8
2011-03-29,129535.91
2011-03-30,130472.78
2011-03-31,131314.04
2011-04-01,133101.73
2011-04-04,133742.24
2011-04-05,134134.2
2011-04-06,132193.55
2011-04-07,132270.03
2011-04-08,131457.44
2011-04-11,130568.38
2011-04-12,127796.02
2011-04-13,127101.06
2011-04-14,126500.02
2011-04-15,127758.45
2011-04-18,125279.16
2011-04-19,126274.63
2011-04-20,128002.62
2011-04-25,127439.15
2011-04-26,127551.84
2011-04-27,125842.63
2011-04-28,125260.38
2011-04-29,125786.29
2011-05-03,121860.75
2011-05-04,120733.8
2011-05-05,120771.36
2011-05-06,122405.44
2011-05-09,122555.7
2011-05-10,122724.74
2011-05-11,120245.45
2011-05-12,121550.84
2011-05-13,119550.5
2011-05-16,118517.47
2011-05-17,120564.76
2011-05-18,119212.42
2011-05-19,117456.26
2011-05-20,118104.25
2011-05-23,118169.99
2011-05-24,119738.33
2011-05-25,119512.94
2011-05-26,121344.23
2011-05-27,121466.32
2011-05-30,120480.24
2011-05-31,121917.1
2011-06-01,119644.41
2011-06-02,121090.67
2011-06-03,120602.32
2011-06-06,118517.47
2011-06-07,119080.94
2011-06-08,118648.94
2011-06-09,119174.85
2011-06-10,117860.08
2011-06-13,116545.31
2011-06-14,117005.48
2011-06-15,115619.22
2011-06-16,114399.26
2011-06-17,114500.92
2011-06-20,114787.43
2011-06-21,115277.26
2011-06-22,115046.21
2011-06-24,114325.32
2011-06-27,114916.82
2011-06-28,116894.64
2011-06-29,116940.85
2011-06-30,116543.44
2011-07-01,118918.67
2011-07-04,119574.86
2011-07-05,117855.82
2011-07-06,117097.96
2011-07-07,116192.23
2011-07-08,114963.03
2011-07-11,112365.99
2011-07-12,111367.84
2011-07-13,113382.62
2011-07-14,111552.68
2011-07-15,111035.12
2011-07-18,109621.07
2011-07-19,109963.03
2011-07-20,110129.39
2011-07-21,112199.63
2011-07-22,112014.79
2011-07-25,111395.56
2011-07-26,110240.29
2011-07-27,108170.05
2011-07-28,109057.3
2011-07-29,109297.6
2011-08-01,108872.46
2011-08-02,105859.52
2011-08-03,103539.74
2011-08-04,97402.96
2011-08-05,98123.84
2011-08-08,89815.16
2011-08-09,94676.52
2011-08-10,95194.08
2011-08-11,98558.22
2011-08-12,99408.5
2011-08-15,100988.91
2011-08-16,100425.14
2011-08-17,101591.39
2011-08-18,98220.2
2011-08-19,96589.27
2011-08-22,96507.27
2011-08-23,99477.56
2011-08-24,98721.32
2011-08-25,97582.4
2011-08-26,98347.76
2011-08-29,101117.6
2011-08-30,101773.62
2011-08-31,103978.56
2011-09-01,106967.08
2011-09-02,103759.89
2011-09-05,100953.6
2011-09-06,104042.34
2011-09-08,105855.5
2011-09-09,102775.86
2011-09-12,102684.75
2011-09-13,101627.84
2011-09-14,102994.54
2011-09-15,103413.66
2011-09-16,104944.36
2011-09-19,104607.24
2011-09-20,102876.09
2011-09-21,102374.97
2011-09-22,97436.62
2011-09-23,97482.18
2011-09-26,98001.53
2011-09-27,98566.43
2011-09-28,96835.27
2011-09-29,97855.74
2011-09-30,95213.46
2011-10-03,92224.94
2011-10-04,92744.28
2011-10-05,92607.61
2011-10-06,95031.23
2011-10-07,93564.3
2011-10-10,97454.84
2011-10-11,97764.63
2011-10-13,98843.84
2011-10-14,100183.82
2011-10-17,98376.19
2011-10-18,100354.69
2011-10-19,99842.08
2011-10-20,97962.51
2011-10-21,100489.59
2011-10-24,103250.49
2011-10-25,102342.18
2011-10-26,103691.15
2011-10-27,107828.01
2011-10-28,108547.46
2011-10-31,105579.72
2011-11-01,104635.44
2011-11-03,105444.82
2011-11-04,106640.91
2011-11-07,107234.46
2011-11-08,107342.38
2011-11-09,104194.77
2011-11-10,103960.95
2011-11-11,106020.38
2011-11-14,105462.81
2011-11-16,105498.78
2011-11-17,103016.67
2011-11-18,102692.91
2011-11-21,101910.51
2011-11-22,101155.08
2011-11-23,99374.44
2011-11-24,99815.1
2011-11-25,99104.64
2011-11-28,101173.07
2011-11-29,99887.05
2011-11-30,102791.84
2011-12-01,105219.99
2011-12-02,104104.84
2011-12-05,106011.39
2011-12-06,107369.36
2011-12-07,105903.47
2011-12-08,103421.36
2011-12-09,105058.11
2011-12-12,103520.28
2011-12-13,102881.77
2011-12-14,101560.25
2011-12-15,101498.17
2011-12-16,100717.68
2011-12-19,98828.56
2011-12-20,102349.6
2011-12-21,101994.84
2011-12-22,103236.51
2011-12-23,103733.18
2011-12-26,103688.84
2011-12-27,103866.22
2011-12-28,101090.19
2011-12-29,101462.69
2012-01-02,103804.14
2012-01-03,106163.32
2012-01-04,106092.37
2012-01-05,104797.48
2012-01-06,104912.78
2012-01-09,105790.82
2012-01-10,106926.07
2012-01-11,107405.0
2012-01-12,107103.45
2012-01-13,105498.14
2012-01-16,107076.84
2012-01-17,107857.32
2012-01-18,110509.19
2012-01-19,110420.5
2012-01-20,111059.07
2012-01-23,111378.36
2012-01-24,111440.45
2012-01-26,112123.37
2012-01-27,112460.39
2012-01-30,111786.34
2012-01-31,112433.79
2012-02-01,114943.75
2012-02-02,114908.27
2012-02-03,115795.18
2012-02-06,115724.23
2012-02-07,117471.45
2012-02-08,116983.64
2012-02-09,116353.94
2012-02-10,113950.41
2012-02-13,116894.95
2012-02-14,115458.16
2012-02-15,116106.64
2012-02-16,117263.49
2012-02-17,117657.88
2012-02-22,117184.62
2012-02-23,116860.35
2012-02-24,117070.69
2012-02-27,115913.83
2012-02-28,117044.39
2012-02-29,116527.31
2012-03-01,118569.34
2012-03-02,120155.64
2012-03-05,118613.16
2012-03-06,114923.48
2012-03-07,117158.33
2012-03-08,118315.19
2012-03-09,117876.98
2012-03-12,117456.3
2012-03-13,121119.69
2012-03-14,120225.76
2012-03-15,119594.74
2012-03-16,119261.71
2012-03-19,119621.03
2012-03-20,118613.16
2012-03-21,117763.05
2012-03-22,116124.16
2012-03-23,115940.12
2012-03-26,117622.82
2012-03-27,115870.0
2012-03-28,114625.5
2012-03-29,113845.5
2012-03-30,113468.64
2012-04-02,114634.27
2012-04-03,113319.66
2012-04-04,111514.25
2012-04-05,111707.06
2012-04-09,110050.65
2012-04-10,108280.3
2012-04-11,107377.6
2012-04-12,110445.03
2012-04-13,108981.43
2012-04-16,108587.05
2012-04-17,109638.74
2012-04-18,110158.08
2012-04-19,109638.88
2012-04-20,109465.81
2012-04-23,107570.71
2012-04-24,108496.62
2012-04-25,108176.45
2012-04-26,108462.01
2012-04-27,107813.0
2012-04-30,107475.52
2012-05-02,108946.6
2012-05-03,108349.52
2012-05-04,105753.49
2012-05-07,106584.22
2012-05-08,105009.29
2012-05-09,103944.92
2012-05-10,104100.69
2012-05-11,103668.01
2012-05-14,99652.83
2012-05-15,98077.9
2012-05-16,97030.84
2012-05-17,94149.25
2012-05-18,94581.92
2012-05-21,98112.52
2012-05-22,95810.71
2012-05-23,95014.59
2012-05-24,94123.29
2012-05-25,94668.45
2012-05-28,95966.47
2012-05-29,94685.76
2012-05-30,93456.97
2012-05-31,94062.71
2012-06-01,92332.03
2012-06-04,92262.8
2012-06-05,90783.07
2012-06-06,93621.39
2012-06-08,94235.78
2012-06-11,93690.62
2012-06-12,95161.7
2012-06-13,95941.17
2012-06-14,95958.31
2012-06-15,96969.12
2012-06-18,97405.99
2012-06-19,98939.34
2012-06-20,98845.11
2012-06-21,95769.85
2012-06-22,95598.53
2012-06-25,92823.09
2012-06-26,92925.88
2012-06-27,91795.14
2012-06-28,90938.53
2012-06-29,93713.97
2012-07-02,94262.2
2012-07-03,96677.87
2012-07-04,96643.6
2012-07-05,97474.52
2012-07-06,95718.45
2012-07-10,92189.19
2012-07-11,92035.0
2012-07-12,91829.41
2012-07-13,93722.53
2012-07-16,92206.32
2012-07-17,92823.09
2012-07-18,93782.5
2012-07-19,95512.87
2012-07-20,92797.39
2012-07-23,91401.1
2012-07-24,90630.14
2012-07-25,90621.58
2012-07-26,93028.67
2012-07-27,97894.26
2012-07-30,98836.54
2012-07-31,96026.84
2012-08-01,97140.44
2012-08-02,95101.69
2012-08-03,98630.95
2012-08-06,100052.94
2012-08-07,98982.17
2012-08-08,100823.89
2012-08-09,100738.23
2012-08-10,101517.75
2012-08-13,101260.77
2012-08-14,99470.44
2012-08-15,99284.12
2012-08-16,101791.21
2012-08-17,101418.54
2012-08-20,101570.99
2012-08-21,101130.56
2012-08-22,101791.21
2012-08-23,100334.39
2012-08-24,99639.86
2012-08-27,99487.4
2012-08-28,99961.71
2012-08-29,97801.89
2012-08-30,97607.08
2012-08-31,97505.44
2012-09-03,97471.56
2012-09-04,95879.22
2012-09-05,96861.73
2012-09-06,99521.28
2012-09-07,96734.68
2012-09-10,99402.7
2012-09-11,101384.66
2012-09-12,102477.27
2012-09-13,105839.82
2012-09-14,105839.82
2012-09-17,105517.97
2012-09-18,105331.63
2012-09-19,104984.36
2012-09-20,105111.41
2012-09-21,104586.28
2012-09-24,105280.81
2012-09-25,102731.37
2012-09-26,102943.12
2012-09-27,102468.8
2012-09-28,100512.26
2012-10-01,101088.21
2012-10-02,100656.25
2012-10-03,99394.23
2012-10-04,98945.33
2012-10-05,99589.04
2012-10-08,100605.43
2012-10-09,100181.93
2012-10-10,99021.56
2012-10-11,100520.73
2012-10-15,101113.62
2012-10-16,101283.02
2012-10-17,101963.04
2012-10-18,101308.24
2012-10-19,99427.81
2012-10-22,99948.29
2012-10-23,97379.49
2012-10-24,96053.11
2012-10-25,97547.38
2012-10-26,96707.9
2012-10-29,96842.22
2012-10-30,97698.49
2012-10-31,96204.22
2012-11-01,98773.02
2012-11-05,98302.91
2012-11-06,100368.03
2012-11-07,98722.65
2012-11-08,96699.51
2012-11-09,96615.56
2012-11-12,95902.0
2012-11-13,96766.67
2012-11-14,94088.73
2012-11-16,92888.28
2012-11-19,94911.42
2012-11-21,94592.42
2012-11-22,95247.21
2012-11-23,96464.45
2012-11-26,95280.79
2012-11-27,94021.57
2012-11-28,94701.55
2012-11-29,97211.59
2012-11-30,96775.06
2012-12-03,97883.17
2012-12-04,96573.59
2012-12-05,96707.9
2012-12-06,97043.69
2012-12-07,98370.07
2012-12-10,99343.86
2012-12-11,99813.97
2012-12-12,99730.68
2012-12-13,99630.75
2012-12-14,100130.41
2012-12-17,100013.82
2012-12-18,101720.97
2012-12-19,102437.14
2012-12-20,103011.74
2012-12-21,102262.26
2012-12-26,102262.26
2012-12-27,101587.73
2012-12-28,101962.47
2013-01-02,105027.0
2013-01-03,106092.93
2013-01-04,104593.97
2013-01-07,103578.01
2013-01-08,102095.71
2013-01-09,102761.91
2013-01-10,103419.79
2013-01-11,103086.69
2013-01-14,103494.73
2013-01-15,103228.25
2013-01-16,103095.01
2013-01-17,104102.65
2013-01-18,103394.8
2013-01-21,103344.84
2013-01-22,102995.08
2013-01-23,103627.98
2013-01-24,101854.21
2013-01-28,99830.61
2013-01-29,100680.02
2013-01-30,98764.69
2013-01-31,99830.61
2013-02-01,100555.11
2013-02-04,99247.69
2013-02-05,98764.69
2013-02-06,98198.42
2013-02-07,97099.18
2013-02-08,97398.97
2013-02-13,97498.1
2013-02-14,96837.1
2013-02-15,96341.35
2013-02-18,95812.54
2013-02-19,95242.43
2013-02-20,93110.69
2013-02-21,93135.48
2013-02-22,94027.83
2013-02-25,93532.08
2013-02-26,94862.35
2013-02-27,95019.34
2013-02-28,94854.09
2013-03-01,94606.21
2013-03-04,93532.08
2013-03-05,92788.45
2013-03-06,96010.85
2013-03-07,97663.36
2013-03-08,97159.34
2013-03-11,97308.07
2013-03-12,96547.91
2013-03-13,95068.91
2013-03-14,94812.78
2013-03-15,94110.46
2013-03-18,94333.55
2013-03-19,93226.37
2013-03-20,92788.45
2013-03-21,92210.07
2013-03-22,91524.28
2013-03-25,90474.94
2013-03-26,92243.12
2013-03-27,92780.19
2013-03-28,92871.08
2013-04-01,92375.32
2013-04-02,90731.07
2013-04-03,91896.09
2013-04-04,90392.31
2013-04-05,91185.52
2013-04-08,90912.85
2013-04-09,92193.55
2013-04-10,92904.13
2013-04-11,91334.24
2013-04-12,90458.41
2013-04-15,87566.52
2013-04-16,89070.3
2013-04-17,87686.79
2013-04-18,87884.43
2013-04-19,88905.58
2013-04-22,89794.97
2013-04-23,90873.76
2013-04-24,90519.65
2013-04-25,90799.64
2013-04-26,89144.4
2013-04-29,90569.06
2013-04-30,92314.89
2013-05-02,91260.8
2013-05-03,91524.33
2013-05-06,91079.63
2013-05-07,92808.99
2013-05-08,91771.38
2013-05-09,91244.33
2013-05-10,90478.47
2013-05-13,89630.26
2013-05-14,89984.37
2013-05-15,90042.02
2013-05-16,90173.78
2013-05-17,90832.58
2013-05-20,91664.32
2013-05-21,92644.29
2013-05-22,93261.92
2013-05-23,93039.57
2013-05-24,93097.22
2013-05-27,92981.93
2013-05-28,92150.19
2013-05-29,89745.56
2013-05-31,88032.67
2013-06-03,88633.82
2013-06-04,89103.22
2013-06-05,87126.81
2013-06-06,87044.46
2013-06-07,85002.17
2013-06-10,84491.59
2013-06-11,81691.68
2013-06-12,80962.91
2013-06-13,83083.6
2013-06-14,80840.09
2013-06-17,80619.01
2013-06-18,80905.59
2013-06-19,78457.38
2013-06-20,79161.55
2013-06-21,77294.69
2013-06-24,75476.95
2013-06-25,76721.53
2013-06-26,77294.69
2013-06-27,78113.49
2013-06-28,77081.8
2013-07-01,77376.57
2013-07-02,72873.17
2013-07-03,73339.88
2013-07-04,74707.28
2013-07-05,73929.42
2013-07-08,73364.45
2013-07-10,74805.53
2013-07-11,76475.89
2013-07-12,73970.36
2013-07-15,76353.07
2013-07-16,76737.9
2013-07-17,77622.21
2013-07-18,77769.59
2013-07-19,77785.97
2013-07-22,79759.27
2013-07-23,80054.04
2013-07-24,79292.56
2013-07-25,80438.88
2013-07-26,80872.84
2013-07-29,80528.94
2013-07-30,79472.69
2013-07-31,78825.84
2013-08-01,80488.0
2013-08-02,79186.11
2013-08-05,79218.86
2013-08-06,77204.62
2013-08-07,77564.89
2013-08-08,80316.06
2013-08-09,81920.9
2013-08-12,82837.96
2013-08-13,83026.28
2013-08-14,82852.17
2013-08-15,83598.59
2013-08-16,84834.32
2013-08-19,84759.68
2013-08-20,83515.65
2013-08-21,82487.26
2013-08-22,84510.87
2013-08-23,85871.01
2013-08-26,84394.76
2013-08-27,82105.75
2013-08-28,82022.82
2013-08-29,81915.0
2013-08-30,83183.91
2013-09-02,83971.79
2013-09-03,84502.58
2013-09-04,84817.73
2013-09-05,85589.03
2013-09-06,87247.73
2013-09-09,88325.89
2013-09-10,88259.54
2013-09-11,87645.82
2013-09-12,87148.21
2013-09-13,88151.72
2013-09-16,87728.75
2013-09-17,88956.19
2013-09-18,91576.94
2013-09-19,90813.94
2013-09-20,88947.9
2013-09-23,90034.35
2013-09-24,90034.35
2013-09-25,89818.72
2013-09-26,89072.3
2013-09-27,88383.94
2013-09-30,86111.52
2013-10-01,87629.23
2013-10-02,87662.41
2013-10-03,86202.75
2013-10-04,87247.73
2013-10-07,86070.05
2013-10-08,85937.36
2013-10-09,87065.27
2013-10-10,87612.64
2013-10-11,87936.09
2013-10-14,90050.94
2013-10-15,91004.69
2013-10-16,91508.8
2013-10-17,91878.46
2013-10-18,91239.95
2013-10-21,92500.17
2013-10-22,93928.42
2013-10-23,91777.65
2013-10-24,90500.62
2013-10-25,89811.7
2013-10-28,92080.1
2013-10-29,90853.49
2013-10-30,91239.95
2013-10-31,91492.0
2013-11-01,90979.51
2013-11-04,91987.68
2013-11-05,90677.05
2013-11-06,89862.11
2013-11-07,88803.53
2013-11-08,87879.37
2013-11-11,88719.51
2013-11-12,87022.42
2013-11-13,88215.42
2013-11-14,90324.19
2013-11-18,91340.77
2013-11-19,89139.59
2013-11-21,88417.06
2013-11-22,88719.51
2013-11-25,88123.01
2013-11-26,86703.16
2013-11-27,86955.2
2013-11-28,87375.28
2013-11-29,88131.41
2013-12-02,85879.82
2013-12-03,84686.81
2013-12-04,84770.82
2013-12-05,85190.9
2013-12-06,85947.03
2013-12-09,86014.24
2013-12-10,85913.42
2013-12-11,84065.1
2013-12-12,84443.16
2013-12-13,83930.67
2013-12-16,84375.95
2013-12-17,84367.55
2013-12-18,86137.65
2013-12-19,87047.79
2013-12-20,86029.1
2013-12-23,86304.65
2013-12-26,86171.05
2013-12-27,86371.45
2013-12-30,86663.69
2014-01-02,84200.47
```

Answer (score 1):

- The original issue might have been resolved with [ValueError: view limit minimum -35738.3640567 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57874226/7758804)
- This error doesn't occur in `matplotlib 3.4.3`, even if the dates are `string dtype`.

  - The `'date'` column can be converted to a `datetime dtype` using `parse_dates` when reading the csv in, or with `pandas.to_datetime` after reading the file in.
- An issue with this code is `plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True)`, but it should be `sharex=False`, because the x-axis of subplots 1, 3, and 5 are not the same as 0, 2, and 4.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import pandas as pd

# read the data from the file, parse the dates and set as index
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])

# Original Series
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12, 10))
axes[0, 0].plot(df.close)
axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
plot_acf(df.close, ax=axes[0, 1])

# 1st Differencing
axes[1, 0].plot(df.close.diff())
axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.close.diff().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])

# 2nd Differencing
axes[2, 0].plot(df.close.diff().diff())
axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
plot_acf(df.close.diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]